# Powershell to automate IE | fill Paiement form issue

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, automation, bots

I'm just starting to use powershell scripts.

I am trying to automate a payment process (for personal use).

But when I enter my payment information via my script the information is not saved on the page (the data acts as a placeholder)

I tried to use a "focus()" before entering the values but it doesn't work :(
(maybe a bad use ?)

I had the idea to simulate an "ENTER" key press after entering my values but I feel like I'm misusing the syntax

Here is an example of my code:

```
$cardnumber = "4000 1000 2000 0000"
$nameoncard = "Alban Mysteriousguy"
$expirationdate = "10/77"
$ccv = "420"
$ie = New-Object -COMObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.Navigate(‘https://secure2.ldlc.com/fr-fr/DeliveryPayment’)
#Achat CB 
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 1; }    #wait for browser idle

#notworking
$Carednumbervar = $ie.document.getElementsByName("CardNumber")
($Carednumbervar |Select-Object -first 1).value = $cardnumber; 

#working
($ie.document.getElementsByName("OwnerName") |Select-Object -first 1).value = $nameoncard; 

#notworking
($ie.document.getElementsByName("ExpirationDate") |Select-Object -first 1).value = $expirationdate; 

#notworking
($ie.document.getElementsByName("Cryptogram") |Select-Object -first 1).value = $ccv; 

#working
$payementButton = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('button') | Where-Object { ($_.ClassName -ceq 'button color2 maxi') }
$CGV = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('label') | Where-Object { ($_.for -ceq 'terms') }
$CGV.click
#$payementButton.click()
```

If anyone have an idea about how can I solve this issue or just a trick that I can try, you are welcome :)

Thanks by advance

PS: To test the script you need to create an account to Ldlc.com, add something in your cart and go to the payment page ( https://secure2.ldlc.com/fr-fr/DeliveryPayment for exemple) if needed I can upload a video of the behavior.

Edit: Here I made a youtube video to show my issue : youtu.be/pTbSWU_cudY

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What does `$ie.document.getElementsByName("CardNumber")` return?

Comment: It return the  field where the script is suposed to wite the number of the credit card. I know this part is partialy working because when the page load I see the numbers on the field but they act like if they are a "placeholder", the page don't recognize this data like if the user wrote it
Here I made a youtube video to show my issue : https://youtu.be/pTbSWU_cudY

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem, but failed. The page displayed is different from yours. If possible, please provide the html code of the page, which will help solve the problem.

Comment: Hello, first of all thank you for your help. 
I assume that if the page displayed is not the same as mine it is because you are in another country. 
I have copied all the source code of the page, you can find it on this link : https://jsfiddle.net/bq6axgm7/

Thanks again for your help. Have a nice day !

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the detailed code. I extracted the relevant html code and performed a simple test. I found that it works correctly. You need to cancel `Enable Protected Mode` in IE.

`Open IE` -> `Tools` -> `Internet Options` -> `security tab` -> uncheck option `Enanle Protected Mode` and apply

Something like this:

[image]